# pass value in database through radio button in form for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem as I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am using `form_for` to submit some values. I am passing a value through hidden field as a role to login a user. User depend on its role. If role is client then user is redirected to clients page, and if role is admin then user is redirect to admin page. I am assigning roles through hidden field as below:
Now I want to remove hidden field and want to assign role through radio buttons. Kindly help me how I can pass role through radio button in form for. I will be very thankful to you for any help.

Comment: Can you show what: `@roles` has? Just do: `puts @roles.inspect`.

Comment: thanks for reply @surya.@roles returns client and admin.In my url there is path like localhost:3000/blog/sign_in?client then @roles login a user as client otherwise as admin if url have admin role.

Comment: People can't help unless they understand what you're trying to do and what exactly situation you have at hand. Can you please provide the code where you create/assign `@roles`?

Comment: i just want two radio buttons.one for client and one admin.If a user check client button then he should redirect to clients page after login other wise if admin button checked then should redirect to admins

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need something like this:

```
<%= f.radio_button :role, 'user', checked: true %>
<%= label :role_user, 'User' %>

<%= f.radio_button :role, 'client' %>
<%= label :role_client, 'Client' %>

<%= f.radio_button :role, 'admin' %>
<%= label :role_admin, 'Admin' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `@roles` is an Array:

```
@roles = ['client', 'admin']
```

then in View you can do:

```
<% @roles.each do |role| %>
  <%= f.label :role, role.humanize, :value => role  %>
  <%= f.radio_button :role, role %>
<% end %>
```

in your controller:

```
before_filter :check_role

def check_role
  if params[:user][:role] == 'client'
    redirect_to client_path
  elsif [:user][:role] == 'admin'
    redirect_to admin_path
  end
end
```

Change `params[:user][:role]` with the correct `params` key to access the passed value in response. Also, change `client_path` and `admin_path` with actual routing helpers you have in your application.